# i am not able to get the data throught below code in nodejs ? it shows TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js

```
app.get('/students', (req, res)=>{
 const studentsData = Student.find();
 studentsData.then(()=>{
    res.status(200).send(studentsData);
   }).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).send(e);
  })
  })
```

I am getting error says that :-
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 3):

You should use the result of the promise to send back, instead of the promise itself:

```
app.get('/students', (req, res)=>{
 const studentsData = Student.find();
 studentsData.then(result => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
 }).catch((e)=>{
  console.log(e);
  res.status(400).send(e);
 })
})
```

Comment: Would be better to convert that handler to an async function to be able to use await.

Comment: @AKX I agree, but that would be a rewrite of the code and not so much an answer to the question.

Comment: Sure, but it would make things a lot clearer. (Besides, modern IDEs such as PyCharm and VSCode could do the async refactoring automatically.)